# How to generate class file with java ASM?

Tags: java, assembly

I have tried

```
    ClassWriter t = new ClassWriter(0);

    t.visitSource("testing.java", null);

    t.visitEnd();

    byte d[] = t.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream p = null;

    try
    {
        p = new FileOutputStream("testing.class");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        p.write(d);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the text within the testing.java is:

```
public class testing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Works!");
    }
}
```

However, When I try to run the class file, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: testing : Unsupported major.minor version 0.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

How would I fix it so that the class file would output "Works!" to the console?

**Edit:**

I don't want it to have to access the jdk files! (<- Ex. javax.tools) That's why I was trying to get ASM to work.

Comment: You appear to be compiling with one version of Java and running with a lower version.

Comment: you also haven't closed the stream, invoke p.close() once you've finished with it

Answer (score 8):

Seems that you are trying to compile Java source file into a class file. That can be done with the Java compiler - the [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) command line program or the tools in the [javax.tools package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html).

ASM is for a different purpose. ASM can be used to create class files on-the-fly, without any source code. Read [ASM's documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/) to learn about Java bytecode and how to produce and read it with ASM.

Here is how a file is compiled using javax.tools package. Or then you could invoke the command line tools using [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Check the documentation for additional arguments - what classpath to use, where to write the files etc.

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class TestingCompile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int result = javac.run(null, null, null, "C:\\path\\to\\Testing.java");
        if (result != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("compile failed: exit " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to create the same class file using ASM, without using the source file. I'm quite sure this is not what you want to be doing - otherwise you wouldn't have had to ask the question. ;)

This is just the output of [ASMifierClassVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifierClassVisitor.html), so the bytes would still need to be written to a file or loaded dynamically into the class loader. I used the `-debug` argument so that ASMifier would show also the source file name and line numbers (the `visitSource`, `visitLineNumber` and `visitLocalVariable` calls are optional, so you could omit them and the related labels if the debug information is not needed).

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

public class TestingDump implements Opcodes {

    public static byte[] dump() throws Exception {

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        FieldVisitor fv;
        MethodVisitor mv;
        AnnotationVisitor av0;

        cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, "Testing", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

        cw.visitSource("Testing.java", null);

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(1, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "LTesting;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(3, l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("Works!");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLineNumber(4, l1);
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l2 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l2);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("args", "[Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l2, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that the library expects a minimum set of certain methods will be called and I believe you don't have enough methods to have it generate a full class.

I suggest you use ASMifier to generate some templates.

---

You have corrupted the file in some way. There was no version 0.0

Comment: @PeterLawrey as you said, ClassWriter#visit() has to be always called before any other visit*() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the Java compiler from your source code to compile any Java source code to the class files. The compiler is written in Java itself and part of the standard jdk release. Try to look for a class called javac.