# Write btytecode to file using Clojure asm library

Tags: java, clojure, bytecode

I'm playing with Java byte-code generation using Clojure with the https://github.com/jgpc42/asm. So far so good, but now I am trying to export the generated bytecode to a .class file. With Java ([code from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158898/how-to-generate-class-file-with-java-asm)), I see is possible with something like the code bellow, but not sure exactly no to translate it to Clojure using the asm library.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

public class TestingDump implements Opcodes {

    public static byte[] dump() throws Exception {

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        FieldVisitor fv;
        MethodVisitor mv;
        AnnotationVisitor av0;

        cw.visit(V1_6, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, "Testing", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

        cw.visitSource("Testing.java", null);

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(1, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "LTesting;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_STATIC, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(3, l0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("Works!");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLineNumber(4, l1);
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l2 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l2);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("args", "[Ljava/lang/String;", null, l0, l2, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Can some one provide some tips and guideline on it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

OK,

looks like it is simple like:

```
  (def test-data
  {:name 'pkg.Main
   ;; :version 16 
   :methods [{:flags [:public :static], :name "main", :desc [[String] :void]
              :emit [[:getstatic System "out"]
                     [:ldc "Hello, World!"]
                     [:invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream "println" [String :void]]
                     [:return]]}]})

(require '[insn.core :as insn])

(insn/write (insn/visit test-data) "/tmp/test")
```

From: https://github.com/jgpc42/insn/issues/6